# How connect Spring Cloud Gateway + Spring Cloud Security + Keycloak

Tags: spring, security, cloud, keycloak, gateway

He has been trying to connect s-c-gateway and s-c-security with Keycloak for a couple of days. I want the modules that are located behind the gateway not to have a keycloak configuration.
Is Spring Cloud Gateway not supported by Spring Cloud Security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue on the [spring cloud gateway github about this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/179#issuecomment-372137963) - a short summary is that there's currently no official support but I'd suggest reading the full github comments

Comment: Thanks, so I must wait on end 2018 :C

Comment: @JakubByByJacob I am from 2019 :) How did you solve that task?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [@EnableWebFluxSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-security-webflux.html) in cloud gateway, since it's reactive project.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question with an answer but now it is possible and very common to integrate `Spring cloud Gateway`, `Spring cloud Security` and `Keycloak`. You can find a good tutorial here:
https://kunkkali.blogspot.com/2020/10/build-j2ee-micro-services-architecture.html
Source code: https://github.com/liqili/spring-microservice-oauth2-keycloak-starter